# Default ADX database

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I have admin access to few ADX clusters. I am building some sort of automation in ADF and I am executing `.show databases` command from each of these clusters in a loop. I have created a generic ADF connection (Linked Service) to talk to ADX clusters to execute the commands, but I am forced to pass name of database to ADX Command activity. Now, in this case database doesn't matter , ideally whatever name I pass , that's the database the command will be submitted against. That's why the ADX Command activity needs it. But in case of `.show databases` command, it's not a database specific command, but ADX Command activity forces me to specify it anyways -- so I have to pass something to it. Now the database names across different clusters are different. I hate hardcoding database names separately for each activity call. If there would be a standard built-in database that's guaranteed to exist for every ADX cluster, I could use that. So is there any such built in system database that I can pass to ADX Command activity so I don't have to specify hardcode database values per cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try passing `NetDefaultDB` as the database name, in this very specific case